# CMake Application and DLL both linking to same static library?

Tags: dll, static, cmake, linker

I'm trying to get something simple going with CMake and I'm running into issues.

I have an Application that needs to link to a DLL that itself links to a Static library. Each of these modules resides in its own folder with its own CMakeLists.txt file.

I use add_subdirectory() to build a project hierarchy, so that the DLL add_subdirectory() adds the Static lib (and links to Static) and the App uses add_subdirectory() to add to the DLL project.

Now, the problem is that in the final project, the CMake makes the App link both to the DLL and the Static Library, although I explicitly ask it in the CMakeLists.txt file to only link to the DLL. Obviously, I don't want the App to link to Static if the DLL already does.

I suspect it has something to do with add_subdirectory() but I don't see how to fix this. Can someone please point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, linkage of the "library1" to the "library2" is **propagated** to all users of "library1" (e.g., an application). This is done whenever "library2" is *SHARED* or *STATIC*.

For supress linkage propagation use *PRIVATE* linking:

```
target_link_libraries(library1 PRIVATE library2)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try it out and accept your answer as soon as I verify it works. (Afk now)

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed.